# Providing command line arguments to jboss standalone.sh

Tags: java, jboss, environment-variables

just want to say I have been reading the forum for a while and have finally decided to join!

I am trying to provide jboss command line arguments to configure jvm variables. My standalone.sh looks as follows;

```
## -*- shell-script -*- ######################################################
##                                                                          ##
##  JBoss Bootstrap Script Configuration                                    ##
##                                                                          ##
##############################################################################

#
# This file is optional; it may be removed if not needed.
#

#
# Specify the maximum file descriptor limit, use "max" or "maximum" to use
# the default, as queried by the system.
#
# Defaults to "maximum"
#
#MAX_FD="maximum"

#
# Specify the profiler configuration file to load.
#
# Default is to not load profiler configuration file.
#
#PROFILER=""

#
# Specify the location of the Java home directory.  If set then $JAVA will
# be defined to $JAVA_HOME/bin/java, else $JAVA will be "java".
#
#JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk"

#
# Specify the exact Java VM executable to use.
#
#JAVA=""

if [ "x$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS" = "x" ]; then
   JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.byteman"
fi

# Uncomment the following line to prevent manipulation of JVM options
# by shell scripts.
#
#PRESERVE_JAVA_OPTS=true

#
# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=GMT"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.policy-permissions=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DEnvironment=DEV"
else
   echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi

# Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debugging
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"

# Sample JPDA settings for shared memory debugging
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=n,address=jboss"

# Uncomment to not use JBoss Modules lockless mode
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.lockless=false"

# Uncomment to gather JBoss Modules metrics
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.metrics=true"
```

If you notice, I am trying to provide my own value named Environment which i wish to set development, uat or production.

In my java application I am trying to receive this value as follows;

```
String environment = System.getProperty("Environment");
```

This always seems to be null and I am not sure why.

Am I configuring this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: this looks correct to me, maybe someone more experienced can shed some light

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can provide it as an argument when standalone.sh is called - in run.sh i believe?